# How to Set Loop on FocusNode

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new in flutter. Here is the code of TextField, and I want those Focusnode comes through a for loop,

```
List myFocusNode;

FormFields(hintText) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
   TextField(
    focusNode: myFocusNode[i],
    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
    style: TextStyle(
      color: Color(0xFF727c8e),
      ),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF960bef)),
        ),
      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFe34fd1)),
        ),
      labelText: hintText,
      labelStyle: TextStyle(
          color: myFocusNode[i].hasFocus ? Color(0xFFe34fd1) : Color(0xFF960bef) ,
          fontSize: 15,
          fontFamily: 'Exo2-VariableFont_wght'),
      ),
    );
   }

}
```

I am getting the below error after run.

```
I/flutter ( 6472): [MediaQuery], state: _ProfileSettingPageState#112a0):
I/flutter ( 6472): The method '[]' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 6472): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 6472): Tried calling: [](0)
```

I am calling this to other class like below,
`FormFields("First Name",),`
Kindly give me a solution.

Comment: It looks like you are not initializing the List anywhere, that's why you are having **null**.
Are you initializing this list with values somewhere? *List myFocusNode;*

Comment: @vinipx `FormFields("First Name" ), ` i am putting this into another page

Comment: Still, the `FormFields("First Name" ),` will simply inject the `labelText` property, but not the myFocusNode list itself.

Comment: can you tell me how to do this?

Comment: To test the loop, please initialize the List with some FocusNode objects ([you can find official documentation about the object here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusNode-class.html) )

also, some more info about [focusNode property here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/focusNode.html)

Comment: try something like `List<FocusNode> myFocusNode = [node1,node2,node3 etc...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your list **myFocusNode** with some FocusNodes

```
List<FocusNode> myFocusNode = [FocusNode, FocusNode, FocusNode, FocusNode .....];

 FormFields(hintText) {
   // expected the length of myFocusNode = 15
   for (var i = 0; i < myFocusNode.length; i++) {
    TextField(
     focusNode: myFocusNode[i],
     textAlign: ........
    );
   }
 }
```